# Problem with Big Curly Brackets in Overleaf

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, brackets

I am trying to make open a big curly bracket with 3 rows and 2 columns in it. This will be used in a Conference Paper that has 2 columns per page, so logically the wideness of each column is relatively small, so the second column in my bracket should continue on the next line. However, with the following code it is continuting to bypass to the other column of the Paper and overlapping with the text there and in case the latex is on the second column of the paper, the rest of teh text just disappears instead of continuing on a new line like the below picture:
[image: image with problem]

What I really want is like this:

[image: desired image]

My code is as follows and all the methods to linebreak do not work and break the text even more.

```
\[ 
\left \{
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \(Val1 \thinspace \thinspace\)   & This is the start of my long line that I want to see its continuation on the second line but it goes out of range of the page and does not appear at all\\
   \(Val2 \thinspace \thinspace\)  &  Otherwise   \\
   \(Val3 \thinspace \thinspace\)  &  Otherwise  \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\]
```

I am using https://www.overleaf.com/

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer with the usage of your code but with `cases` of `amsmath` package as @JouleV suggested:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ 
\left \{
  \begin{tabular}{cp{9cm}}
  \(Val1 \thinspace \thinspace\)   & This is the start of my long line that I want to see its continuation on the second line but it goes out of range of the page and does not appear at all\\
   \(Val2 \thinspace \thinspace\)  &  Otherwise   \\
   \(Val3 \thinspace \thinspace\)  &  Otherwise  \\ 
  \end{tabular}\right.
\]

\[
\begin{cases}
Val1  & \parbox[t]{9cm}{This is the start of my long line that I want to see its continuation on the second line but it goes out of range of the page and does not appear at all}\\
   Val2 &  \text{Otherwise}   \\
   Val3   & \text{Otherwise}  \\ 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm !